# Password trouble in nodemailer and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer with gmail and I need to include my password somehow. The issue is that my password contains both single and double quotes. e.g. my"annoying'password.

I've tried to escape either of the quotes, but Google refuses my password.
`"my\"annoying'password"`

`'my"annoying\'password'`

I can login just fine, but I can't use it in my script.

Here is the code creating the mailer object.

```
var mailer = email.createTransport({
  service : "gmail",
  auth    : {
    user     : "myemail@gmail.com",

    // neither of these work
    password : "my\"annoying'password",
    // password : 'my"annoying\'password',
  }
});
```

Is this possible or am I going to have to change my password?

**UPDATE**

The error I get is:

```
[Error: Invalid login]
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

Comment: It should work with "my\"annoying'password", but for testing purposes try this ugly code "my" + '"' + "annoying'password"

Comment: @Guilherme Reda Afraid not :(. Still getting the error.

Comment: the error says that the password is the problem? can you post the returned error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry. Me being stupid.

```
var mailer = email.createTransport({
  service : "gmail",
  auth    : {
    user     : "myemail@gmail.com",

    // neither of these work
    pass : "my\"annoying'password",
    // pass : 'my"annoying\'password',
  }
});
```

Not

```
var mailer = email.createTransport({
  service : "gmail",
  auth    : {
    user     : "myemail@gmail.com",

    // neither of these work
    password : "my\"annoying'password",
    // password : 'my"annoying\'password',
  }
});
```

Notice that `password:` changed to `pass:`

Comment: I was having the same problem. Thanks dude.

Comment: omg hector, i love you man! I had the same shitty problem :D thanks so much1!!

Comment: Did you put your actual password for your gmail as the value? I don't want to put my password anywhere, not even an environment variable

Comment: Yes I did. I don't think there is any way around having your password somewhere.